# Order lattice panel by regression intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

Example dataset [here](http://textuploader.com/ktr0)

Let us build a simple lattice plot from this data for linear regression, with separate panels for each Subject

```
 xyplot(Measurement~HOL|Subject,groups=Treatment,data=Data,
 type=c('p','r'),auto.key=T,aspect="xy")
```

The issue is, I would like to visually inspect if the slopes-and-intercepts are correlated. Thus, I would like to order the panels by linear-regression intercept as opposed to by Subject (this was done in Douglas Bates' book "lme4: Mixed-effects modeling with R" Figure 3.1, but I cannot find example code). I know I can change the order of panels by hand by adding

```
index.cond=list(c(1,2,3, etc))
```

But this is extraordinarily inefficient, especially since I would like to do this for multiple response variables.

Does anyone have an automated way to do this? I am also open to attempting this in ggplot2 if it has any built in functions, but as I understand, there is no way to easily change the aspect to a 45degree such as the

```
aspect="xy"
```

does in Lattice.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order by regression intercept, it's best to run the regression. For example, with your data we can do

```
cf<-sapply(Data$Subject, function(x) 
    coef(lm(Measurement~HOL, data=subset(Data, Subject==x))))
```

which will give a slope/intercept for each person, we can then create a new factor of Subjects ordered by the intercept with

```
Sx<-reorder(Data$Subject, cf[1,])
```

and then use that variable as the grouping variable in the plot

```
xyplot(Measurement~HOL|Sx,groups=Treatment,data=Data,
 type=c('p','r'),auto.key=T,aspect="xy")
```

[image]

And in `ggplot` you can fix the ratio of `x/y` with `+coord_fixed(ratio=1)`

Comment: Very nice! I was thinking I would have to do an approach like this. I'd upvote your Answer, but do not have sufficient reputation...